# Python: Renaming columns with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Why isn't my attempt to rename columns working? I could swear I am following the right syntax and I am not getting any errors... it's simply not doing it.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
header = list(range(17))
energy = pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls', 
                       usecols = [2, 3, 4, 5], 
                       skiprows = list(range(17)), 
                       skipfooter = 38)

energy.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 2': 'Country', 
                       'Petajoules': 'Energy Supply', 
                       'Gigajoules': 'Energy Supply per Capita', 
                       '%': '% Renewable'})
```

[image: Screenshot of my code and output in Jupyter]

Answer (score 4):

What you are missing is `inplace=True` to rename and apply on the original dataframe object.

*Note: inplace=True returns None inplace=False returns a copy of the object with the operation performed.*

```
import pandas as pd

df_sorted = pd.DataFrame({'duration':[1,0,2,0],'Count':[23,23,2,1]})
df_sorted.rename(columns={'duration':'NewName'},inplace=True)
print(df_sorted)
```

Comment: Alternatively, just reassign it instead of modifying it in place; it is the preferred method, as it is planned to deprecate `inplace` args in a (probably very distant) future pandas version.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options. You can re-assign the output of `energy.rename()` by using `energy=energy.rename()` or you can add the optional argument `inplace=True`.

[From the documentation for `DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html):

> **inplace** : *bool, default False*
>
> Whether to return a new DataFrame. If True then value of copy is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options for [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)

1. Update with the result or here directly return it because you don't modify it then

```py
energy = energy.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 2': 'Country', 'Petajoules': 'Energy Supply', 
                                'Gigajoules': 'Energy Supply per Capita', '%' : '% Renewable'})

return energy.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 2': 'Country', 'Petajoules': 'Energy Supply', 
                              'Gigajoules': 'Energy Supply per Capita', '%' : '% Renewable'})
```

2. Change the current object

```py
energy.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 2': 'Country', 'Petajoules': 'Energy Supply', 
                       'Gigajoules': 'Energy Supply per Capita', '%': '% Renewable'},
              inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont necessarily need inplace=True. you just have to save it back to your original df

```
energy = energy.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 2': 'Country', 
                   'Petajoules': 'Energy Supply', 
                   'Gigajoules': 'Energy Supply per Capita', 
                   '%': '% Renewable'})
```